# Name the devcontainer volume

Tags: vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

When building my devcontainer in vscode, a new volume is built named `vscode`. What could I do to make this volume have another name instead of `vscode`?
Here is my `devcontainer.json` file:

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/go
{
    "name": "Go",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/go:1-1.21-bullseye",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/github-cli:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/stuartleeks/dev-container-features/shell-history:0": {},
        "ghcr.io/guiyomh/features/golangci-lint:0": {},
        "ghcr.io/guiyomh/features/goreleaser:0": {},
        "ghcr.io/guiyomh/features/gotestsum:0": {}
    },

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    "customizations": {
        // Configure properties specific to VS Code.
        "vscode": {
            // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
            "settings": {
                "go.toolsManagement.checkForUpdates": "local",
                "go.useLanguageServer": true,
                "go.gopath": "/go"
            },
            "extensions": [
                "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
                "mongodb.mongodb-vscode",
                "MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-pt-BR",
                "nhoizey.gremlins",
                "quicktype.quicktype",
                "redhat.vscode-yaml",
                "streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker",
                "streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker-portuguese-brazilian",
                "alefragnani.bookmarks",
                "mhutchie.git-graph",
                "zxh404.vscode-proto3",
                "golang.go"
            ]
        }
    },

    "runArgs": ["--userns=keep-id", "--name=GeneralgoPackContainer"],
    "containerUser": "matheus",
    //"privileged": true,
    //"securityOpt": ["seccomp=unconfined"],

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "go version",

    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    "remoteUser": "matheus"

    //"--userns=keep-id", 
}
```